# mod_rewrite seems to ignore a rule with a question mark?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect

`domain.com/page?user=something`

to

`domain.com/page/something`

with

```
RewriteRule ^page?user=(\d[^/]+) /page/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

For some reason that's not working though. It seems to be just ignoring it even. When I go to `domain.com/page?user=something` nothing happens. mod_rewrite is enabled and all other rules are executing. I assume it could be due to the `?` in the URL but I might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these 2 rules in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page(?:\.php)\?user=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^page/([^/.]+)/?$ page?user=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```